# Use request timeout (Net.WebClient)

Tags: vb.net, webclient

Can you set a timeout for a request using

```
Net.WebClient()
```

I know that its possible with the WebRequest, however Id like to use the WebClient.

EDIT: I created a new Class called WbClnt containing this code:

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class WbClnt
    Inherits WebClient
    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal uri As Uri) As WebRequest
        Dim w As WebRequest = MyBase.GetWebRequest(uri)
        w.Timeout = 5000
        Return w
    End Function
End Class
```

However, I cant call this function from my main form using WbClnt.GetWebRequest, probably because its protected.

Comment: Simple answer, **yes**, you have to inherit the `WebClient` and override `GetWebRequest`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you don't like the WebClient class as it is, you can derive a custom control from it, which will give you access to the underlying HttpWebRequest. Then you can set a Timeout using that class directly. It could be useful for other things, too. Handling Cookies, for example. Or, you could learn about HttpClient...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ How can I inherit the WebClient?

Comment: Create a new class and then [**inherit**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/objects-and-classes/inheritance-basics) the `WebClient` in your new class. Now you can use your new class anywhere you would have used the `WebClient` or need it.

Comment: Okay, but by only Inheriting the WebClient Im still not able to set a timeout for the request, am I?

Comment: Please re-read my comment again from my first post... `you have to inherit the WebClient and override GetWebRequest`...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I did, but how can I call the Override Function from another Form now?

Comment: `Im still not able to set a timeout for the request`, with the code from your comment, does it fix this issue?

Comment: Please do not add code, ask about it and then remove it... you just need to use the class just like you would for `WebClient`.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It might sort out my problem with the timeout, but how can I actually send request now? Do I need to call the overrides function?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I cant use the class / the overrides function in the class on my other form.

Comment: "can't" means what? What happens when you try? All this will be much clearer if you show us actual code and error messages, instead of giving vague descriptions of your problem. Please edit the question to show what the specific issue is.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: Again, "can't" means what, exactly? It's not possible to fix a problem of "can't". Show us how you tried to call it, and what error you got.

Comment: @ADyson Cant means Im not able to call the function at all. Using `WbClnt.GetWebRequest` will give me an error like "Not accessible"

Comment: Ok I see. It occurs to me that you don't need to actually call GetWebRequest yourself. All you're doing here is overriding an internal function of the class, so that it sets a timeout. You actually call the Downloadstring method (or any of the other public methods to trigger a request) just as you normally do. Internally, the class will then use your modified version of GetWebRequest in order to actually carry out the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all of the comment's above, here is a simple implementation on what I was suggesting to do.

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class MyPatientlyWebClient
    Inherits WebClient

#Region "Variables"
    Private ReadOnly _timeOut As Integer = 100000
#End Region

#Region "Properties"

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determine's how to long to wait for request.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public ReadOnly Property HowLongToWait
        Get
            Return _timeOut
        End Get
    End Property
#End Region

#Region "Constructors"
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal timeOut As Integer)
        MyBase.New()
        If timeOut <= 0 Then timeOut = 100000
        _timeOut = timeOut
    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "Overrides"

    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal address As System.Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim w As System.Net.WebRequest = MyBase.GetWebRequest(address)
        w.Timeout = HowLongToWait
        Return w
    End Function

#End Region

End Class
```

**TO USE**

```
Dim myPaWebClient As New MyPatientlyWebClient(120000)
Dim str As String = myPaWebClient.DownloadString("https://www.google.com")
```

You can set the property if you want; need to change the `ReadOnly`, I just whipped something up for you real quick.